# in whatsapp, how do you display contacts in alphabetical order?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I  used to be able to get whatsapp to show contacts in alphabetical order but now the option has gone. I can't see all my contacts listed from a-z.  It shows them in order of the last message between us.

How can I display whatsapp contacts  in alphabetical order?

**added**
[image]

Comment: WhatsApp shows contacts in alphabetical order by default if you are viewing all contacts. There is no option to change that.

Comment: @MANI where does it show contacts then?   I see 3 tabs.  Chats, Status, Calls.  What tab are you talking about?

Comment: You are getting confused. What you are seeing is chat screen. There's *new message* & *new call* bubbles below on bottom right, click on them to see all your contacts in alphabetical order.

Comment: @MANI i've included a picture.   Please tell me where you think I should be looking.  I don't see a "new call" bubble.

Comment: @MANI I don't see a new call bubble. I do see a bubble that looks like it might be what you mean by a "new text" bubble.   And I see it brings up the contacts.  You can post that as an answer

Comment: It's okay. These things won't stay like that for longer periods. User interface changes every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot on the right, is showing you your active chats. This goes by the order of the last message you received.

To view all your WhatsApp contacts in an alphabetical order, click on the green circle on the bottom right of the screen. This will bring up a list of all your contacts that use WhatsApp.

Comment: you write "click on the green circle on the bottom right of the screen." <-- green circle with white rectangle inside.